# Does anyone know how to test EventListeners in spring?

Tags: spring-4, event-driven-design

I am looking into the spring domain event features in spring 4.2 and it looks really greate.
it is however, a bit messy to test.

Given the following business logic :

```
public DomainEvent<Order> CreateOrder(Order order) throws OrderRejectedException {
//INSERT BUSINESS LOGIC HERE
 this.publisher.publishEvent(new OrderAccepted(order)); 
}
```

The publisher is inserted in the constructor, so I can mock it quite easilly,

In my junit class i would like to assert that the applicationEvent is published from my service.
Idially this should be done without mocks.
Does anyone know if there exists a "test publisher" that keeps all the events being published, so i can inject that in my service during test and assert on this test instance of the publisher ? 
I can ofcause write my own, but this sounds like a general problem so it should in MHO exist a default test instane